# Tcp reliabity handled at hardware level?

Tags: tcp, udp, network

At work we are moving from a TCP to a UDP protocol for a kind of 3D engine because we have 1s hang when a packet is lost. Since our engine is not designed to handle packet loss nor out of order arrival, we use a library (Lidgren) to do reliable UDP. So far, this is working as expected but it is slightly slower than TCP (20 to 30 %) in term of latency. A coworker of mine argues that this is because the reliability and ordering of packet involves CPU overhead for UDP while it is handled directly by the network adapter for TCP. So, is the network adapter doing some special work when using TCP and not UDP to spare CPU work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network adapter is a layer-1/2 device that really doesn't know or care about the layer-3 (IP, etc.) or layer-4 (TCP, UDP, etc.) protocol that is carried as the payload of layer-2 (ethernet, etc) protocol. The NIC is happy to carry something like IPX that uses SPX as its layer-4 protocol.

Comment: Not in general, as many modern network cards are using TCP offload engine where all TCP/IP stack would be handled by ASIC. Especially on 1Gbps and faster connections, which works pretty good to reduce overhead on CPU.

Comment: Cards that do TCP offload also do UDP offload, and this would not explain the difference in TCP/UDP speed the question.

Comment: There is many NIC's designed especially for low latency with full UDP stack offload. So we cannot generalise that NIC's only do layer 1/2 which was true few years back. Right now most SOHO NIC's doing partial offloading of checksum, ARP etc. Of course is not the answer for this particular question. But I believe I've explained why would you expect bigger latency in my answer.

Comment: @Datagram.Network - Although some cards support  TCP offload engine, in practice it isn't used in common operating systems. The reason is that different manufacturers have different view of how a TCP offload engine works, and the entire network stack would require a rewrite per each manufacturer. Checksum offload? Yes. Large send offload? Yes. Large receive offload? Yes. But full TCP offload? No, not usually supported by the operating system.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good place to list what kinds of TCP offloading features a NIC hardware can have.

The most basic form of offload is **checksum offload**. It improves performance somewhat, but not much. Checksum is something that is very easy to do in hardware. Checksum offload, however, can show strange checksums when a .pcap is captured, so it is not fully transparent to the user. The solution to the .pcap problem is to turn checksum offload off.

**Large send offload** works because often an application write()'s a large buffer such as 64 kilobytes. Let's assume that of this, the TCP window and congestion control allow sending 24 kilobytes immediately. The operating system constructs a virtual TCP segment of 24 kilobytes and the 24 kilobyte virtual TCP segment passes through the operating system stack only once. Then the NIC breaks the large virtual 24 kilobyte segment into smaller physical segments. The idea here is to reduce software overheads by handling large virtual packets instead of small physical packets. The per-packet processing overhead applies then to a larger chunk of data. So, the effect is similar to running a large MTU.

**Large receive offload** is large send offload in the oppoisite direction, and works with the interrupt mitigation features of a NIC. In this case, the idea is that the NIC won't interrupt the operating system per each arriving packet but actually waits for a while for more packets to arrive. If the further packets seem to be consecutive packets belonging to the same connection, they are combined into one larger virtual segment (let's say a 32 kilobyte segment). Then the operating system's stack will process the large 32 kilobyte virtual segment once, and the packet processing overhead is amortized over 32 kilobytes instead of the usual 1500 bytes. This is the receive-side equivalent of large send offload. However, this feature will break routers, so it cannot be used in machines doing IP forwarding.

All of these previously listed TCP offload features are stateless. They are nice because they do not require practically any modifications to the operating system's TCP stack. There is a more full way of performing TCP offloading, called **TCP offload engine**. In it, part of the state of the TCP connection is offloaded to the NIC, and the NIC performs part of the TCP packet processing. However, the problem is that different manufacturers have different views of what the NIC should do. Thus, in practice if there are 10 NIC vendors, you need 10 different copies of the operating system TCP stack, each tailor-modified to work with a specific NIC vendor. Not going to happen! Also, once the rules are hardcoded to an ASIC, you cannot fix bugs in the rules.

In modern Linux systems using good network interface cards, checksum offloading, large send offloading and large receive offloading are used. However, TCP offload engine is not supported by any standard Linux kernel. Same probably applies to Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

High speed adapters (1 Gb and above) do have special hardware to process TCP on the NIC itself, thereby saving CPU cycles. This is usually found on servers since they process more traffic than user workstations.  "TCP offload" can be disabled through the adapter settings if it is causing application problems.

Comment: Not in general, as many modern network cards are using TCP offload engine where all TCP/IP stack would be handled by ASIC. Especially on 1Gbps and faster connections, which works pretty good to reduce overhead.

Comment: @Datagram.Network You are right -- I haven't kept up with NIC developments.   I will revise my answer.

Comment: I am running Windows 10 and have a Intel Ethernet Connection I218-LM card. Is there a way to know if this adapter has such a device?

Comment: Based on the data sheet (Google is your friend), it doesn't appear to have it.

Comment: Doesn't support full stack offload only partial for ARP, Checksum etc.

Comment: Cards that do TCP offload also do UDP offload, and this would not explain the difference in TCP/UDP speed the question.

Comment: @RonMaupin The question is why his app-based reliable transfer is slower.  And I think the fact that his error checking is done at the application level in software, vs. using TCP in hardware, would explain (some of ) the difference.

Comment: What is offloaded for TCP isn't the reliability of TCP. It is things like checksums, which are also offloaded for UDP. The TCP process in the network stack still deals with the windowing and missing and out-of-order packet delivery.

Comment: x2 what Ron said - TOE is good for offloading error checking and achieving speedup through special DMA mechanisms.  The offload engine doesn't have an arbitrary amount of buffer to be retransmitting lost frames.  I'll also say that there are still a substantial number of situations where TOE needs to be disabled in actual practice as the state of driver compatibility and full OS support can be sketchy.

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually, segmentation can also be offloaded for TCP, but not for UDP. So, if the application does write() of 10 kilobytes, and the TCP congestion/window conditions allow sending all at once, the TCP/IP stack in the operating system is invoked only once, even though the MTU is typically 1500 bytes which is less than 10 kilobytes. The NIC then breaks the packet into pieces. For UDP, such segmentation offloading is not done. So, if sending large amount of data at once, TCP may actually be faster than UDP.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I assume that lidgren is working on Layer 7 (application layer). Which would increase CPU overhead and latency.
Packets are still handled as normal by lower layers supported by operating system, as Lidgren don't change how UDP is handled by operating system. So to process additional checks on higher layer it would take time and use additional resources. Not really sure but maybe lidgren is adding additional headers in data which are handled by application and to process this you need CPU and is where latency could increase.

Comment: Thanks. So you confirm that packet reliability and reordering for TCP are handled by the operating system (thus consuming CPU time) and not some specific hardware component on the network adapter? And if someone implement reliability and reordering for UDP in the application layer performance should be equal to the one using TCP (assuming the implementation is equally good)

Comment: I'm not saying that would be better as TCP, it could have a lower re transmission time than TCP but doesn't mean that would be faster in general. As reliability is handled on Layer 7 which takes more time than on lower layer.

Comment: Could you explain why if reliability is implemented on Layer 7 it would take more time than on lower levels?

Comment: Please see below video how  encapsulation and decapsulation works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGnqIILfE9Q

If you adding another information on layer 7 in data it means that this data need to encapsulated/decapsulated by application and this would take additional time.

Comment: Probably because it is written in a higher level language and runs in user space.  The IP stack is optimized for speed, runs at the kernel level, and is a higher priority task.

Comment: Didn't think about the code running directly in the kernel Is there a way to find out by how much it helps?

Comment: You would need to modify UDP stack which whole design was done to be unreliable. But to be honest I would personally modify TCP/IP retransmission time and you would achieve better performance than using lidgren on application layer.

Comment: @codec-abc See my revised answer, based on DatagramNetwork's comments